# Can ASP.Net Core ILogger.BeginScope wrap the middleware pipeline

Tags: logging, asp.net-core

I have created a custom middleware to handle exceptions in my Api app.

I want to correlate a request id with the exception and any other logging I do in the app. I then want to handle any exceptions and respond to the client with the `requestId` I generated.

This would allow them to contact me with a `requestId` which I could look up in my logs and see what was going on when they received their error.

Here is the `Invoke` of my middleware and the sending of the `requestId` in the response.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid();
    var requestScopeLogger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("AppRequest");

    using (requestScopeLogger.BeginScope("Request {requestId}", requestId))
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex, requestId);
        }
    }
}

private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, Guid requestId)
{
    ...
    var response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { errorMessage = clientResult.message, requestId });

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)clientResult.code;

    return context.Response.WriteAsync(response);
}
```

The middleware is registered before anything else (StaticFiles, Swagger, Mvc) in my `Startup.Configure`

Everything seems to be working correctly when I test throwing exceptions in my Api business logic or controllers.

Is this an acceptable use of `ILogger.BeginScope`?
Is it ok to wrap the middleware pipeline in this way despite it being `async`?

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: If someone uses serilog, consider to use LogContext as described in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460579/how-do-i-get-a-serilog-enricher-to-work-with-dependency-injection-while-keeping/57488163#comment115865101_57488163